# How to enable DHT in Ktorrent in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ktorrent

I recently downloaded KTorrent but now I want to download something that requires Distributed Hash Tables to be enabled...

*How do I enable DHT in KTorrent?*

Comment: DHT is not an option (at least not anymore; you used to be able to enable it in "settings" "preferences" "bittorrent"). It is either supported or not, and except for a few ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients#Features_I )  all torrent programs support it. What is important though: DHT uses UDP and not TCP so your firewall and your router might block these.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2019-02-23, KTorrent allows to enable DHT, as [Rinzwind pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033957/how-to-enable-dht-in-ktorrent-in-ubuntu-16-04#comment1681960_1033957), under

> **Settings → Preferences → BitTorrent**

The setting for this [is called](https://www.reddit.com/r/kdeneon/comments/asp8k5/needs_to_know_how_to_turn_on_dht_for_ktorrent/) *Use DHT to get additional peers*.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually
*Settings* → ***Configure Ktorrent*** → *Bittorrent*, at least on my version of Ktorrent (version 5.1.1).